# VB.Net Excel Automation how to handle Sensitivity Labels

Tags: vb.net, excel-automation

When I'm creating an Excel file for a user in VB.Net, I am getting an error ("You can't perform this action when the file is read-only") when I try to save the file and it seems to be because a Sensitivity Label hasn't been chosen.  I haven't been able to find any documentation on handling Sensitivity Labels when performing Excel Automation so I was wondering if anyone has run into this issue or knows of any documentation?  Is there a way to set the Sensitivity programmatically?

Comment: Have you made sure that the file is not readonly on the file system level, and that you didn't open it as read only?

Comment: I'll verify now.  This may take a little bit of time as I don't have the issue on my computer so I'll have to wait to hear back from the user.  With that said, the report had been working fine for years until the latest waves of Windows/Office updates went out.  IT may have put new policies in place as well to require the Sensitivity Label but I'm still waiting to hear back about that for sure.

Comment: The file was not readonly so it's another classic case of a horrible error message from Excel.  I fixed the issue which I'll put into an answer for others that may see this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a template file (stored in database and brought down to the local machine) that I set the Sensitivity on and then populated that instead of creating the Excel file through the Automation process.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is Python because that is what I am using, but since `win32com.client` is just a COM wrapper, this should (with the proper VB syntax) work for you.

You will need the following data, which you can extract from a file where you previously manually set the sensitivity label to your desired value:

```
existing_sl = existing_doc.SensitivityLabel.GetLabel()
label_id = existing_sl.LabelId
label_name = existing_sl.LabelName
```

`label_id` will be a UUID and `label_name` a string.
Then, with this data, you can create and set a new sensitivity label as follows.

```
label_id = <the label ID you retrieved from the existing file>
label_name = <the label name your retrieved from the existing file>

new_sl = another_doc.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
new_sl.ActionId = str(uuid.uuid1())
new_sl.AssignmentMethod = 1
new_sl.ContentBits = 0
new_sl.IsEnabled = True
new_sl.Justification = ''
ew_sl.LabelId = label_id 
new_sl.LabelName = label_name 
new_sl.SetDate = '2022-08-15T07:02:00Z'
new_sl.SiteId = str(uuid.uuid1())
another_doc.SensitivityLabel.SetLabel(new_sl, new_sl)
```

The `uuid.uuid1()` function is just the Python function to create a random UUID. You could also use something else or a fixed one. I did not test it thoroughly, but it works with the random one at least. As far as I could find out, the `SiteId` variable need not be the same as in the original label. As for `SetDate`, I was just lazy and set it to some value. Being completely proper, you could use `now` or an equivalent function to generate a (properly-formatted) datetime string.

`AssignmentMethod`  uses the [MsoAssignmentMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/msoassignmentmethod-enumeration-office) enumeration. `1` is just "*The label was manually selected*".

The Python code requires the following imports

```
import win32com.client
import uuid
```

You can find some references [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.sensitivitylabel.setlabel) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.sensitivitylabel.getlabel).

If you manage to get it to work in VB, feel free to post the result :)