# Add sensitivity label to email via powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I've got a need to send email within PowerShell and have all the components except the sensitivity label.  For example:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = 'someone@co.com'
$Mail.Subject = 'Special subject'
$SigString=Get-Content "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\sig.htm"
$Mail.HTMLBody = 'blah blah blah.'
$Mail.HTMLBody += $SigString
$Mail.Send()
```

Unfortunately when this runs I'm prompted for the sensitivity label.  I thought `"Sensitivity = "` might work and it does allow values `0` thru `3` but that doesn't help.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: `Sensitivity` is a property of an [Outlook MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sensitivity). `$Mail.Sensitivity = 0` should do it.

Comment: @Theo, I've tried $Mail.Sensitivity = 0 and values 1 thru 3 as well.  Regardless of value after I hit enter to send I still get prompted for what sensitivity label I want to use.  The popup comes from "Microsoft Azure Information Protection" - "This email cannot be sent without a label.  Please select:" and then gives options of "Public" thru "Restricted Sensitive".

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @Dave

Comment: @visleck, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and I could not find any way to do this "outside" of an Office program as this seems to be a built-in enterprise function allowing only a given set of sensitivity labels set by your comany.

If Python can be an alternative, you [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73402656/1665217) can automate sensitivity label setting. Alternatively, having a [pre-stored template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66425162/1665217) that can be copied and then edited would also work with PS.