# How to set sensitivity level for Outlook email via PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, outlook

I am creating a script to send automatic email to end users via PowerShell. I have a specific requirement, as the attachment of the email contains sensitive information, I need to set the sensitivity label to either "Protected" or "Restricted". Does anyone know the PowerShell command for setting the sensitive level in outlook?

I tried with below code, and it didn't work.

```
$server = "relay.companyname.com" 
$subject = "Subject Needed to be discussed" 
$attachment = "D:\Scripts\test.csv" 
$body = Get-Content -Path "D:\Scripts\Email Content.txt" | Out-String
$recipients = "support@companyname.com" 
$sensitivity = "Restricted" 
Send-MailMessage -To $recipients -From "support@companyname.com" -Subject "$subject" -Attachment $attachment -Body $body -SmtpServer $server
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for responding @lit. I updated my original post with full code.

Comment: I tried both `$Sensitivity` and `$SensitivityLabel` and both didn't work.

Comment: I do not see a `Sensitivity` parameter for `Send-MailMessage`. I suggest that you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68398086/447901 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem